# xcode syntax color coding explained?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

Can anyone give me a quick rundown of the color syntax meanings in xcode?

I am running into some problems and understanding the color coding I am sure will help me out.  Currently I have some variables that are light blue and I think they need to be black but I am not sure of the difference?

```
masterViewController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithDestination: destination];
```

I believe my masterViewController here should be colored black and not the light blue it is currently colored - I am assuming I defined or initialized something wrong somewhere.

First day in xCode so I am pretty damn confused!

Comment: looks like it has something to do with variable scope, I believe my problems lie with my variables being out of scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to: `Xcode` => `Preferences` => `Fonts & Colors`

You'll see that each syntax highlighting colour has a brief explanation next to it.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 12.3 the heading is Themes rather than Fonts & Colours

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul said, it's self-explaining in the `Fonts & Colors`

[image]